# Disable fwupd integration in KDE Discover

Tags: kubuntu, fwupd, discover-software-center

I'm running the 22.04 Kubuntu beta on an XPS 13 7390. I would like to disable `fwupd`, as an automatic Dell BIOS update bricked my laptop so badly last time that even the USB recovery wouldn't work. Fortunately, it was still under warranty, otherwise I would have had to pay for a motherboard replacement. Needless to say, I don't want any more automatic BIOS updates from Dell.

I tried uninstalling `fwupd` (`sudo apt-get purge fwupd`), but then KDE Discover would hang because it couldn't find it (received an error like `The name org.freedesktop.fwupd was not provided by any .service files`). I then re-installed it and specifically disabled the service (`sudo systemctl stop fwupd`; `sudo systemctl disable fwupd`) but Discover happily re-launches it whenever it opens.

Is there a way to disable the `fwupd` integration with KDE Discover so I can still use Discover while removing `fwupd` from my system?

Comment: Hello. Since 22.04 does not exist yet this question is off topic.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc. *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more poking around I figured it out. The integration is provided by the `plasma-discover-backend-fwupd` package, so I just needed to remove that too.

`sudo apt-get remove fwupd plasma-discover-backend-fwupd`

*Voilà*. No more remote bricking from my laptop manufacturer.

Comment: Since this is an answer to an off topic question about an OS that does not exist at this time, not really an answer. The OS in question may work differently when released.

Comment: @David That's how it works on 21.10 as well, I don't see a reason why this would change.

Comment: This is how it's worked since at least 20.04 judging by the presence of `plasma-discover-backend-fwupd` in the repos. Should I delete my question & answer?